# Crystal reports bad references

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have downloaded this installer: http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0.exe that should install all the ddls for CR, however when trying to make a Report Document I get an error because there's a missing reference, I have added references to all the CR ddl VS founded:

[image]

The CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports doesn't have the "Engine" library, only a "TemplateEngine" which doesnt have the element.
Should I install anything else? :S

Comment: Fixed the cause of the exception, good sir ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns that the installer (or maybe VS) didn't made the dll visible to VS or something like that, I had to browse for the dlls and add them manually, the strange thing is that some libraries did show and some others not